# Updating fields based on results of a query

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

So in this scenario a person can order products. I have a query that returns the result of an order ID and give the products that person ordered.
My issue is adapting this to an update query so the quantity from the OrderProduct table/query is then subtracted from the amount of stock in the Product Table.

SQL to create the table supplied below and the query to get the results

```
CREATE DATABASE StockControl;

CREATE TABLE Membership (
    MemberID int NOT Null,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Primary Key(MemberID)
);

CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT Null,
    MemberID int,
    Primary Key(OrderID)
);

CREATE TABLE Product (
    ProductID int NOT Null,
    Price int,
    Stock int,
    Primary Key(ProductID)
);

CREATE TABLE OrderProduct (
    ProductID int,
    OrderID int,
    Quantity int
);

INSERT INTO Membership(MemberID,LastName,FirstName)
VALUES (2,'Me','Too'),(33,'Darren','Kelly');

INSERT INTO Orders(OrderID,MemberID)
VALUES (1,33),(5,2);

INSERT INTO Product(ProductID,Price,Stock)
VALUES (1,30,12),(2,25,12),(3,25,12),(4,25,12),(5,25,12),(6,25,12),(7,25,12),(8,25,12),(9,25,12),(10,25,12);

INSERT INTO OrderProduct(ProductID,OrderID,Quantity)
VALUES (1,5,1),(3,1,4),(9,1,6),(10,1,2);
```

This is the query to return all products as part of orderID 1, in the full version this will be able to be variable.

```
SELECT OrderProduct.ProductID, OrderProduct.OrderID, OrderProduct.Quantity, Product.Price, [Quantity]*[Price] AS Cost
FROM Product INNER JOIN OrderProduct ON Product.ProductID = OrderProduct.ProductID
GROUP BY OrderProduct.ProductID, OrderProduct.OrderID, OrderProduct.Quantity, Product.Price, [Quantity]*[Price]
HAVING (((OrderProduct.OrderID)=1))
ORDER BY OrderProduct.OrderID;
```

This returns the correct result but when trying to implement this to an update I get stuck. I want it so it looks through the 3 results and will subtract 4 from product 3, 6 from product 9 and 2 from product 10

Attempt so far

```
UPDATE SingleOrder INNER JOIN Product ON SingleOrder.ProductID = Product.ProductID SET Product.Stock = Product.Stock-SingleOrder.Quantity WHERE ((Product.ProductID=SingleOrder.ProductID));
```

If this is not clear I am happy to update the question etc.

Thanks

Comment: Ideally, would not update table with stock balances. Save transactions and calculate balances when needed. Access does not allow UPDATE action with a non-editable (non-updatable) query which is what an aggregate query is. This is a common topic. Your attempted code should be edited into the question, not a comment.

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html. If you really must save, an UPDATE can be done with DSum() domain aggregate function or with VBA procedure.

Comment: However, there are no aggregate functions in your query so why are you using GROUP BY? Should you have `Sum([Quantity]*[Price]) AS Cost`?

Comment: This is a project I inherited hence the GROUP BY and the extra fields in the query. I will look in to DSum but this project wouldnt really allow VBA to be used too often and its been over a decade since I looked at VBA but will keep it as a reminder